# Retrieve Certain Data From DB and Send It To View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Problem**

This obviously doesn't work since it was a shot in the dark, What's the best way to retrieve data with certain id and then send/display data to view

**Model**

```
public partial class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Details()
    {
        ProfileContext db = new ProfileContext();
        var data = (from c in db.Profiles
                    where c.Id == 1
                    select c).ToString();

        return View(data);
    }
```

**View**

```
    @model Learning4.Profile

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Profile</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

**Data**

|**Id**  |**Firstname**  |**Lastname**  |
|1    |John                |Doe                |

Comment: Replace `.ToString()` with `.FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wanting to return a single object so you need to use `.FirstOrDefault()` (your query returns a collection, even through it may contain only one element)

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    ProfileContext db = new ProfileContext();
    var data = (from c in db.Profiles
                where c.Id == 1
                select c).FirstOrDefault();
    // or 
    data = db.Profiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
    return View(data);
}
```

Comment: if I wanted to only retrieve one piece of data for example Firstname only, is there a possibility I can send it through a viewbag.Firstname ? would .FirstOrDefault() do the trick?

Comment: `string data = db.Profiles.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => x.FirstName);` will return just the value of the `FirstName`